# Process prompt directives inside $psvar without PROMPT_SUBST

Tags: zsh, colors, prompt

I'm using `precmd` to generate a coloured `git` status in my prompt.

I generate a sting like `%F{green}master%f%F{red}%f`, and assign it to `$psvar[1]`.

My prompt includes `%1v` to display the text.

However, I'm not seeing green and red text, but rather the literal value that was assigned.

Is there any way to get `zsh` to parse the contents of `$psvar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prompt expansion isn't recursive. You have `%1v` in your prompt, so the content of `$psvar[1]` is inserted in your prompt.

Instead of putting prompt expansion directives in `$psvar`, put prompt contents. Insert the terminal escape sequences for color changes. You can use [`colors`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-colors) for that.

```
autoload -U colors
colors
… {
  psvar[1]="$fg[green]$branch$fg[default]"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This `zsh-users` mailing list post](https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2005/msg00863.html) says:

> The results of percent-expandos are not re-expanded,
>   so whatever gets inserted by `%v` appears literally in the final prompt.

So it seems the only way is to use `set -o prompt_subst`.